# How to install nano on boot2docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker, nano

I'm running the boot2docker VM in windows and need to modify the init scripts within the VM.  Currently my only option is VI, and it's a pain.  I'd just like to use nano, but it's not available.

It's running:

```
docker@boot2docker:/c$ uname -a
Linux boot2docker 3.18.5-tinycore64 #1 SMP Sun Feb 1 06:02:30 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There is no apt-get or any package manager.  How can I just get nano added so I can edit files easily?

EDIT:

@John-Petrone 's answer works, but after it's installed, running nano gives the error:

```
Error opening terminal: cygwin.
```

In case anyone else has that problem, the issue is $TERM was set to cygwin.  Not sure why.  I just:

```
TERM=xterm-color
```

And then nano worked! ( if set to any other available terms in /usr/share/terminfo/x funky characters showed up )

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Boot2Docker is based on Tiny Linux which uses `tce-load` to install packages. The list of packages in the repository can be found here:

http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/tcz_2x.html

You'll see that the nano packages is nano.tcz , so you'll run something like:

```
tce-load -wi nano
```

This article: http://lowtek.ca/roo/2015/modify-boot2docker-iso/ should also be helpful along with this one: http://www.gerrelt.nl/RaspberryPi/wordpress/tutorial-unpluggable-squeezelite-player-on-tinycore/#Search_and_install_NANO_extension

Comment: It totally installed, but when I run it, it gives the error "Error opening terminal: cygwin."  Any idea of that?  I get into docker by launching git bash and then running "boot2docker ssh".

Comment: ok but how do you keep it from being deleted everytime you restart the host?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the tar.gz package from [nano website](http://www.nano-editor.org/download.php).